# Google chart can only display once upon running the app

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

My google chart can only be loaded once when I run the app. when I navigate to other pages and go back to the page which has the google chart, the chart will not display. I have to refresh or run the app again in order to display the chart.

```
<section>
<html>
<div class="container"></div>

<div id="columnchart_values" style="width: 1200px; height: 700px;"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ["Week", "# of F2F=0"],
        ["WK1", 9],
        ["WK2", 5],
        ["WK3", 6],
        ["WK4", 0],
        ["WK5", 0],
        ["WK6", 0],
        ["WK7", 0],
        ["WK8", 0],
        ["WK9", 0],
        ["WK10", 0],
        ["WK11", 0],
        ["WK12", 0]
      ]);

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      var options = {
        title: "Dashboard",
        titleTextStyle: {
            fontSize: 21
          },
        'backgroundColor': 'transparent', 
        width: 1600,
        height: 650,
        bar: {groupWidth: "70%"},
        legend: { position: "top" },
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
      chart.draw(view, options);
     }
  </script>

<div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 1200px; height: 700px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Calls', 'People'],
          ['F2F = 0', 6],
          ['1 < F2F < 5', 8],
          ['F2F > 9', 5]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Period: 2QWK3',
          titleTextStyle: {
            fontSize: 21
          },
          'backgroundColor': 'transparent',   
          is3D: true,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
</html>
</section>
```

Comment: Call your `script` on `window.onload`

Answer (score 0):

Call the required `script` on `window.onload` and call a empty function on `window.onunload`

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<section>
  <html>
  <div class="container"></div>

  <div id="columnchart_values" style="width: 1200px; height: 700px;"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      google.charts.load("current", {
        packages: ["corechart"]
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ["Week", "# of F2F=0"],
          ["WK1", 9],
          ["WK2", 5],
          ["WK3", 6],
          ["WK4", 0],
          ["WK5", 0],
          ["WK6", 0],
          ["WK7", 0],
          ["WK8", 0],
          ["WK9", 0],
          ["WK10", 0],
          ["WK11", 0],
          ["WK12", 0]
        ]);

        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        var options = {
          title: "Dashboard",
          titleTextStyle: {
            fontSize: 21
          },
          'backgroundColor': 'transparent',
          width: 1600,
          height: 650,
          bar: {
            groupWidth: "70%"
          },
          legend: {
            position: "top"
          },
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
        chart.draw(view, options);
      }
    };

    window.onunload = function(){}; 
  </script>

  <div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 1200px; height: 700px;"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Calls', 'People'],
        ['F2F = 0', 6],
        ['1 < F2F < 5', 8],
        ['F2F > 9', 5]
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Period: 2QWK3',
        titleTextStyle: {
          fontSize: 21
        },
        'backgroundColor': 'transparent',
        is3D: true,
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>

  </html>
</section>
```